# GCloud Rails application and keeping Redis password in an .env file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, redis, sidekiq

I have a Rails 5.2.3 (Ruby 2.6.3) project hosted on Google Cloud.

I'm currently working on setting up Sidekiq and Redis, following [this guide from Google's docs](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-ruby-rails-activejob-sidekiq).

I've decided to go with the `foreman` option in the `Deploying to App Engine flexible environment` section of the docs, and am stuck on figuring out the `app.yaml` file. Specifically, I'm stuck on how I can supply the Redis URL, Redis password and Rails Secret Key without exposing it in plaintext in my git history.

I can't find info about this anywhere on the GCloud site. The only mention of ENV files I found are [these pages of the GCloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/config/appref), but these only make it so that I can specify specific ENV variables to make available to my app on GCloud, which isn't applicable to me in this situation.

Is there any way for me to have the `app.yaml` file read from my `.env`, or even better, from my `secrets.yaml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually realized today that I misinterpreted the docs, although Google didn't do a great job in the first place with making this clearer.

If you look at the [docs I referenced](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/config/appref) in my OP, they do clarify that the `environment_variables` simply enables you to pass ENV variables into the app via the `app.yaml` file. I don't actually need to supply this section from the docs

```yaml
env_variables:
  REDIS_URL: redis://[REDIS_IP_ADDRESS]:6379
  REDIS_PASSWORD: [PASSWORD]
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: [SECRET_KEY]
```

The above can simply be provided in the `sidekiq.rb` initializer with an `.env` or `credentials.yml` file instead, keeping things secure.

```rb
# initializers/sidekiq.rb

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  Rails.env.production? ?
    config.redis = { url: Rails.application.credentials.redis_url,
                     password: Rails.application.credentials.redis_password
    } :
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/1' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  Rails.env.production? ?
    config.redis = { url: Rails.application.credentials.redis_url,
                     password: Rails.application.credentials.redis_password
    } :
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/1' }
end
```

I've pushed up a PR to the Docs to make this option clearer to future users.